# Gradle project Sync failed , How to fix?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I imported a material Dialog library from Github.
 https://github.com/drakeet/MaterialDialog

And I imported the library in Android Studio. 
However, now The Android Studio says "Gradle project sync failed, basic functionality (editing, debugging) will not work properly.

I tried alternative answers to similar problems from other questions here, 
[Gradle project sync failed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29459590/gradle-project-sync-failed)

[Android Studio Gradle project sync failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663299/android-studio-gradle-project-sync-failed)

But, none works for me .

The error I get in console is : Error:Dependency ZyiaAlarm:materialDialog:unspecified on project app resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency. File: F:\ZyiaAlarm\materialDialog\build\outputs\apk\materialDialog-release-unsigned.apk

My doubt is: Any way to restore the things back, I mean to get the gradle as it was as I am a beginner, there's much to learn about gradle. 
OR
anyway to fix this library I imported ?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: how do you import it ??

Comment: https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio [Method - 2 ]

Comment: I think your question answer is here:
[how-to-import-android-project-as-library-and-not-compile-it-as-apk-android-stud][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536491/how-to-import-android-project-as-library-and-not-compile-it-as-apk-android-stud

Comment: leave it .. just add compile 'me.drakeet.materialdialog:library:1.2.2'  in your build.gradle .. see [link](https://github.com/drakeet/MaterialDialog) step 1. using gradle.

Comment: build.gradle file of project of or the module ?

Comment: then the error  : Error:Dependency ZyiaAlarm:materialDialog:unspecified on project app resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency. File: F:\ZyiaAlarm\materialDialog\build\outputs\apk\materialDialog-release-unsigned.apk

Comment: build.gradle in the src folder

Comment: Nope, doesn;t work! still the error! Anyway to rollback everything at once ? :(

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

It is not clear how do you import it.

If you would like to build **locally** this library, you should have this type of structure:

```
root
  MaterialLib
    build.gradle
  app
    build.gradle
  build.gradle
  settings.gradle
```

where `MaterialLib` is the folder [MaterialDialog/library](https://github.com/drakeet/MaterialDialog/tree/master/library) from github.
You haven't to import the other folders from github.

Also in

`app/build.gradle` you should have:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':MaterialLib')
 }
```

and in the `settings.gradle` you should have:

```
include ':app',':MaterialLib'
```

**However I suggest you avoiding the local library**.

Remove the MaterialLib (don't import code from github).

Just add to your `app/build.gradle` these lines:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'me.drakeet.materialdialog:library:1.2.2'
}
```

In this you should have this type of structure:

```
root
  app
    build.gradle
  build.gradle
  settings.gradle
```

and in the `settings.gradle` you should have:

```
include ':app'
```